# How to create HTML pages using AMFPHP (on server)

Tags: html, flash, amfphp

I have AMFPHP installed on my server. I have a flash app that can call it's methods. I want to create some HTML (on server created) pages which will contain HTML code and results of AMFPHP functions. How to create such thing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did this a while back, but unfortunately don't have the code on this computer.  However, here's a place to get you started:

http://www.flash-db.com/Tutorials/hello/flashamfphp.php

...and in general:
http://www.google.com/search?aq=0&oq=amfphp&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=amfphp+tutorial